# How to map route json and pages html in NODEJS

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, node.js

I am trying understand how to map route json (data) and pages html in application NodeJS +  ExpressJs + Angular.

I mapped the html and its work, but the json i dont know how I should to map.

I have two mapping, one for html and other json

```
// habilitando HTML5MODE
app.all('/*', function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/views/index.html"); 
});
```

And

```
//TODO: THIS NOT WORK
app.get('/contrato/lista', function (req, res) {
res.send({ some: "object literal" });
});
```

But not work /contrato/lista this show me the page index.html. 
I wish that angular consume my json from uri

Bellow is my code

```
var express = require('express');
var app =  express();
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.set('views', __dirname + 'views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');

var routes = require('./routes');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
extended: true
}));

// habilitando HTML5MODE
app.all('/*', function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/views/index.html"); 
});

//TODO: THIS NOT WORK
app.get('/contrato/lista', function (req, res) {
res.send({ some: "object literal" });
});

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
console.log('Started Success http://localhost:' +         server.address().port);
});
```

Comment: You're sending index.html to all routes under root with `/*`. Try changing it to `/`.

Comment: Its work, very nice.I don't have much experience :( Thanks man

Comment: No problem. Good luck on your project!